# required single bean but 2 were found in simple spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. So I am working on a simple application where I have 2 services `EnglishLanguageService` and `SpanishLanguageService`. In the end, I would like to print `Hello` and `Hola` when the app runs but I am getting the error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in controller.ConstructorInjectedController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - profileEnglishLanguageService: defined in file [/Users/user/Downloads/depdency-injection-example/target/classes/services/EnglishLanguageService.class]
    - profileSpanishLanguageService: defined in file [/Users/user/Downloads/depdency-injection-example/target/classes/services/SpanishLanguageService.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I will paste my code down below.

MainApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"controller" , "services"})
public class DepdencyInjectionExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // returns application context
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DepdencyInjectionExampleApplication.class, args);

        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(PropertyInjectedController.class).getGreeting());
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(ConstructorInjectedController.class).getGreetings());

    }
```

ConstructorInjectedController class

```
@Component
public class ConstructorInjectedController {

    private final GreetingService greetingService;

    public ConstructorInjectedController(GreetingService greetingService) {
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }

    public String getGreetings() {
        return greetingService.sayGreetings();
    }
```

PropertyInjectedControllerClass

```
@Controller
public class PropertyInjectedController {

    public GreetingService greetingService;

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greetingService.sayGreetings();
    }

}
```

GreetingService interface

```
public interface GreetingService {

    String sayGreetings();

}
```

EnglishLanguageService class

```
@Service
public class EnglishLanguageService implements GreetingService {

    private GreetingService greetingService;

    public EnglishLanguageService(@Qualifier("english")
                                                 GreetingService greetingService){
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }

    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return greetingService.sayGreetings();
    }
```

EnglishServiceImpl

```
@Profile("english")
public class EnglishServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

SpanishLanguageService

```
@Service
public class SpanishLanguageService implements GreetingService {

    private GreetingService greetingService;

    public SpanishLanguageService(@Qualifier("spanish")
                                                 GreetingService greetingService){
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }
    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return greetingService.sayGreetings();
    }
```

SpanishLanguageServiceImpl

```
@Profile("spanish")
public class SpanishServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return "Hola";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the annotations wrong. `@Profile` is used for something completely other than you think so it should be removed.

You are basically saying to spring "please inject a specific greeting service in class X please".

Right now spring doesn't know which bean you want since you have two different ones implementing the same interface. So we use the `@Qualifier` annotation to tag a bean, and also to target it during injection.

Fist your implementation should have either a `@Service` or a `@Component` so that spring finds it during the component scan, and instantiates it as a spring managed bean. This combined with a `@Qualifier` so that we tag it, so we later can pick this tag during injection:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("english")
public class EnglishServiceImpl implements GreetingService {

    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Here we inject the greeting service and use our qualifier to tell spring which bean we want to inject of the available ones.

```
@Service
public class EnglishLanguageService implements GreetingService {

    private GreetingService greetingService;

    public SpanishLanguageService(@Qualifier("english") GreetingService greetingService){
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }

    @Override
    public String sayGreetings() {
        return greetingService.sayGreetings();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done exactly what you said but now it's saying it sees 4 different beans instead of one

Comment: Rember that you need to use qualifier on every plave you want to inject it, also in your controllers.